# Aligning Plots in an RMarkdown pdf

Tags: r, markdown

I'm trying to arrange 20 similar plots in a 10x2 grid in RMarkdown.

When I do `par(mfrow=c(10,2))`, the console complains that my margins are too big. I imagine this is because, it is trying to fix all 20 plots in a single area rather than break them up. Adjusting my margins gives way too small of a plot.

I've tried using grid.arrange and plot_grid to no avail. Can anybody tell me how to turn this code into a 10 x 2 readable grid of plots?

```
for (i: 1:20){ plot(train[train$ID==i]$Date,train[train$ID==i]$Sales)}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `facet_wrap` :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(train, aes(Date, Sales)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ID, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: It still squishes the plots to make the y-axis unreadable and the data just a straight line.

Comment: In that case, please provide data to debug the issue.